# Make BeautifulSoup Data into a DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python. But I am scraping the web for data and get the data but am having trouble putting the data into a dataframe. It seems that I can only get one line of data in the dataframe.

```
    n=range(2009,2021)

url2 ='https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/'
url3 ='-school-stats.html'

for n in n:
    all = url2+str(n)+url3
    r = requests.get(all)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    league_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'per_match_toggle sortable stats_table')
    for team in league_table.find_all('tbody'):
        rows = team.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            pl_team = row.find('td', class_ = 'left')
            if pl_team == (None):
                continue
            pl_wins = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[1]
            if pl_wins == (None):
                continue
            pl_loses = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[2]
            if pl_wins == (None):
                continue
            pl_total_points = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[16]
            if pl_total_points == (None):
                continue
            pl_total_points_againest = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[17]
            if pl_total_points_againest == (None):
                continue
            pl_FG_percentage = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[22]
            if pl_FG_percentage == (None):
                continue
            pl_3_percentage = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[25]
            if pl_3_percentage == (None):
                continue
            pl_FT_percentage = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[28]
            if pl_FT_percentage == (None):
                continue
            pl_total_rebounds = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[30]
            if pl_total_rebounds == (None):
                continue
            pl_assist = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[31]
            if pl_assist == (None):
                continue
            pl_steals = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[32]
            if pl_steals == (None):
                continue
            pl_turnovers = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[33]
            if pl_total_rebounds == (None):
                continue
            print(n,
                  pl_team.text, 
                  pl_wins.text, 
                  pl_loses.text, 
                  pl_total_points.text, 
                  pl_total_points_againest.text, 
                  pl_FG_percentage.text,
                  pl_3_percentage.text,
                  pl_FT_percentage.text, 
                  pl_total_rebounds.text,
                  pl_assist.text,
                  pl_steals.text,
                  pl_turnovers.text,
                 )
            data = {'Year': n,
                   'Team': pl_team.text,
                   'Wins': pl_wins.text}
```

The Output gives me this example (1000 more rows):

```
2009 Air Force 10 21 1821 1936 .440 .377 .674 879 378 155 70
2009 Akron NCAA 23 13 2403 2171 .418 .332 .708 1199 446 270 80
2009 Alabama A&M 8 19 1761 1954 .388 .267 .665 948 298 224 90
2009 Alabama-Birmingham 22 12 2461 2244 .455 .337 .707 1169 430 224 69
2009 Alabama State NCAA 22 10 2202 2025 .466 .329 .634 1130 445 182 153
```

But when I print "data" I only get one line I know its not a DataFrame but I cant get the DF to work either:

```
{'Year': 2020, 'Team': 'Youngstown State', 'Wins': '18'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a great effort for someone new to Python. One good thing to know is that a `DataFrame` is not a native data structure in Python so Python doesn't understand what a DataFrame is and cannot create one without another library. So you will want to download and install the `Pandas` library, and perhaps start by reading through the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) so you can learn how to initialize DataFrames from data.

In your code, the `data` variable you created is a dictionary. I would also caution you that when you are using loops, all of your variables reset on each iteration of the loop, so you will want to store the information somehow. I would recommend lists for this purpose: on each iteration of the loop, append the new data to a list you have initialized beforehand (outside of the loop).

Then you can pass each of these lists of your data to the pd.DataFrame() method to construct your DataFrame. You'll see how I chose to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

n=range(2009,2021)

url2 ='https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/'
url3 ='-school-stats.html'

## initialize all of the lists but make sure they don't refer to the same empty list
pl_team_list, pl_wins_list, pl_loses_list, pl_total_points_list, pl_total_points_againest_list, \
pl_FG_percentage_list, pl_3_percentage_list, pl_FT_percentage_list, pl_total_rebounds_list, \
pl_assist_list, pl_steals_list, pl_turnovers_list = ([] for i in range(12))

for n in n:
    all = url2+str(n)+url3
    r = requests.get(all)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    league_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'per_match_toggle sortable stats_table')
    for team in league_table.find_all('tbody'):
        rows = team.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            pl_team = row.find('td', class_ = 'left')
            if pl_team == (None):
                continue
            pl_wins = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[1]
            if pl_wins == (None):
                continue
            pl_loses = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[2]
            if pl_wins == (None):
                continue
            pl_total_points = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[16]
            if pl_total_points == (None):
                continue
            pl_total_points_againest = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[17]
            if pl_total_points_againest == (None):
                continue
            pl_FG_percentage = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[22]
            if pl_FG_percentage == (None):
                continue
            pl_3_percentage = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[25]
            if pl_3_percentage == (None):
                continue
            pl_FT_percentage = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[28]
            if pl_FT_percentage == (None):
                continue
            pl_total_rebounds = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[30]
            if pl_total_rebounds == (None):
                continue
            pl_assist = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[31]
            if pl_assist == (None):
                continue
            pl_steals = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[32]
            if pl_steals == (None):
                continue
            pl_turnovers = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'right')[33]
            if pl_total_rebounds == (None):
                continue

            ## append the text to each list
            pl_team_list.append(pl_team.text)
            pl_wins_list.append(pl_wins.text)
            pl_loses_list.append(pl_loses.text)
            pl_total_points_list.append(pl_total_points.text)
            pl_total_points_againest_list.append(pl_total_points_againest.text)
            pl_FG_percentage_list.append(pl_FG_percentage.text)
            pl_3_percentage_list.append(pl_3_percentage.text)
            pl_FT_percentage_list.append(pl_FT_percentage.text)
            pl_total_rebounds_list.append(pl_total_rebounds.text)
            pl_assist_list.append(pl_assist.text)
            pl_steals_list.append(pl_steals.text)
            pl_turnovers_list.append(pl_turnovers.text)

            # print(n,
            #       pl_team.text, 
            #       pl_wins.text, 
            #       pl_loses.text, 
            #       pl_total_points.text, 
            #       pl_total_points_againest.text, 
            #       pl_FG_percentage.text,
            #       pl_3_percentage.text,
            #       pl_FT_percentage.text, 
            #       pl_total_rebounds.text,
            #       pl_assist.text,
            #       pl_steals.text,
            #       pl_turnovers.text,
            #      )

            # data = {'Year': n,
            #        'Team': pl_team.text,
            #        'Wins': pl_wins.text}

## initialize your DataFrame by passing a dictionary of your lists of data
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Team': pl_team_list,
  'Wins': pl_wins_list,
  'Loses': pl_loses_list,
  'Total Points': pl_total_points_list,
  'Total Points Against': pl_total_points_againest_list,
  'FG Percentage': pl_FG_percentage_list,
  '3 Percentage': pl_3_percentage_list,
  'FT Percentage': pl_FT_percentage_list,
  'Total Rebounds': pl_total_rebounds_list,
  'Assist': pl_assist_list,
  'Steals': pl_steals_list,
  'Turnovers': pl_turnovers_list
  })
```

Then `df` looks like this:

[image]